How do I print and trim a line for a specific amount of words stored with string and variables?
import numpy as np 
add_name1 = np.array([30, 4000, 5000, 60]) #array1 
add1 = np.array([600, 50, 4000, 3000000])  #array2

  for item_a, item_b in zip(add_name1, add1):
          print( item_a,"         ", item_b)** 

current print out result:
30            600
4000            50
50000           4000
60          3000000
i wanted to control the spacing of the part from item_a to item_b in order to make them look like they're on the same column?
#hope for print out result:
30          600
4000        50
50000       4000
60          3000000

This question is similar to: How to print a string at a fixed width?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For Python 3.6+
You can use string formatting to achieve this. To fix the alignment, you can use f-strings with fixed-width formatting.
Before Formatting
for item_a, item_b in zip(add_name1, add1):
    print(item_a, "         ", item_b)

Output:
30           600
4000           50
5000           4000
60           3000000

After Formatting
for item_a, item_b in zip(add_name1, add1):
    print(f"{item_a:<10} {item_b:<10}")

Output:
30         600       
4000       50        
5000       4000      
60         3000000   

For Python 2.6+ and 3.0+
Use str.format() to achieve this as below.
for item_a, item_b in zip(add_name1, add1):
    print("{:<10} {:<10}".format(item_a, item_b))


Use the built-in zip() function to get pairs of values from both arrays. Use the built-in format() function to get the desired output formatting. The format string "{:< 10d}" means, format an integer value into a column which is 10 digits long and left-aligned.
import numpy as np 
add_name1 = np.array([30, 4000, 5000, 60]) #array1 
add1 = np.array([600, 50, 4000, 3000000])  #array2

# zip() to iterate pairs of values from both arrays
# use a format string to get the desired output
for a, b in zip(add_name1, add1):
    print("{:< 10d}     {:< 10d}".format(a, b))


I believe what you can do is
print(str(item_a).ljust(10), item_b)

The str.ljust() will fill the rest of the string with empty spaces.
